# How label the complex eigenvalues of a matrix in ascending order of their imaginary part in Octave?

Tags: matrix, octave, eigenvalue

When the function `eig(a)` is used, Octave does not seem to order complex eigenvalues in any particular order (while for real eigenvalues, Octave stores the eigenvalues and their eigenvectors in ascending order).

I need to order the complex eigenvalues (and also their respective eigenvectors) of a matrix in ascending order of their imaginary part. Is there any built in routine to do that?

If not, how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sort` function has a 2nd output argument that gives the indices into the input in sorted order. For your case, if `d` is the vector of eigenvalues:

```
[~,I] = sort(imag(d));
d = d(I);
```

You can use the same `I` to sort the corresponding eigenvectors
`V` in the same order:

```
V = V(:,I);
```

Comment: What does the `~` stand for in `[~,I]`?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: It means to ignore that output argument. The first output argument is the sorted array, but we don't need it.